# All increasing sequence of length k of first n whole numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, sequence

How can I find all the increasing sequence of length k first n whole number ?

**Constraints**

**1<=k<=2000**

**1<=n<=2000**

**for k = 3 n=4**

```
0 0 0 
0 0 1 
0 0 2 
0 0 3 
0 0 4 
0 1 1 
0 1 2 
0 1 3 
0 1 4 
0 2 2 
0 2 3 
0 2 4 
0 3 3 
0 3 4 
0 4 4 
1 1 1 
1 1 2 
1 1 3 
1 1 4 
1 2 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 4 
1 3 3 
1 3 4 
1 4 4 
2 2 2 
2 2 3 
2 2 4 
2 3 3 
2 3 4 
2 4 4 
3 3 3 
3 3 4 
3 4 4 
4 4 4
```

Here I can see  there is a pattern that sum of occurrence of each number in all the series is same.For the above case all the numbers occurs 21 times overall means :

Occurrence of 0 - 21

Occurrence of 1 - 21

Occurrence of 2 - 21

Occurrence of 4 - 21

**Similarly for k=3 n=2**

Occurrence of 0 - 15

Occurrence of 1 - 15

Occurrence of 2 - 15

Occurrence of 3 - 15

**For k=3 n=3** this number is 10

How can I find this number   ?

Comment: There are `Chose(3999,2000)` such sequences for n=2000,k=2000. That's awfully a lot. (For general `n,k`, it's `Choose(n+k-1,k)`

Comment: Oh I was only doing directly increasing sequences. My mistake.

Comment: Is this an assignment or a programming contest/challenge? If its a contest, which one is it?

Comment: It's not an assignment or a programming contest/challenge?I was going through all the concepts where we have to find increasing sequences so I got stuck in this problem

Comment: @rici Why did you marked my question duplicate while it is clearly different from the above question.There number of such sequence are asked while I asked the actual sequnces

Comment: @sagar: I don't think that your question really has an answer, if you expect to be able to enumerate sequences with large n and k (and in this context, even 100 is large: for n=k=100, there are 90548514656103281165404177077484163874504589675413336841320 possible sequences. In the lifespan of the universe, you couldn't enumerate them all. However, I added an enumeration algorithm to the answer to the question marked as duplicate.